# Drop Rows with Consecutive Elements and ID is equal

Tags: python, pandas

I need to remove consecutive duplicates of “instance” where the session is the same. In this example, the instance of 5 in session 2 should not be removed because it is in it’s own distinct session.

Input:

| session | instance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 |

Desired Output:

| session | instance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 |

What I am currently using is getting rid of all consecutive duplicates, even if the session is different, how can I add another expression that ensures only consecutive duplicates are removed for each unique session. It is important that all duplicates are not removed, for example non-consecutive duplicates should be retained within their distinct sessions.

My current code is:

df = df.loc[df[‘instance’].shift(-1) != df[‘instance’]]

Comment: And does your current code work?

Comment: My current code gets rid of all consecutive duplicates, even when the session is different. I need to modify my code somehow to account for sessions but I am completely stuck. The current code would get rid of session 2 completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your idea can be generalized to compare any amount of columns quite easily. Just compare the whole `df`, not only `df[‘instance’]`.

```
df.loc[~(df.shift(-1) == df).apply(all, axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   session  instance
0        1         3
2        1         5
3        2         5
5        3         2
6        3         5
7        3         2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'session': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'instance': [3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.loc[(df['session'] != df['session'].shift()) | (df['instance'] != df['instance'].shift())]

print(df)
```

output:

```
   session  instance
0        1         3
1        1         5
3        2         5
4        3         2
6        3         5
7        3         2
```

The condition `(df['session'] != df['session'].shift())` checks if the current "session" value is different from the previous row's "session" value. The condition `(df['instance'] != df['instance'].shift())` checks if the current "instance" value is different from the previous row's "instance" value.

By combining these conditions with the logical OR operator `|`, we ensure that only rows where either the "session" or the "instance" value has changed from the previous row are selected.